# How to add automated test result for a particular test in ALM Octane using API

Tags: java, selenium, octane-sdk

I am trying to post the test result along with test step using ALM Octane API, but I am not able to do that.

This is what I have tried to post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test_result>
    <test_runs>
        <test_run status="Passed" duration="140" name="Test">
        <steps>
        <step duration="60" name="Anish test Step 1" status="passed" ></step>
        <step duration="60" name="Anish test Step 2" status="passed" ></step>
        <step duration="60" name="Anish test Step 3" status="passed" ></step>
        </steps>
        </test_run>

    </test_runs>
</test_result>
```

Comment: Can you please add any error message that you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error .But the test runs are not getting update in the ALM Octane GUI.

Comment: The response which I get is :{
    "status": "queued",
    "id": 1808
}

Comment: If you have any Idea, How to add test runs along with the steps using the API ,just tell me how to do it